# get entity with condition on related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-clause

I have an Entity `User` with an attribute `List<User>` with many to many relation. This works. Now, I want to get `User` who are not in the `List<User>` of a particular User and they have a particular name containing my research.

So I do it :

```
List<User> users = db.User
.Where(user => user.Name.Contains(research)
.Where(user => user.UserId != UserConnected.UserId)
.ToList();
```

It's work but here, I don't exclude the fact that users can't be in List.
I thought to do something like :

```
.Where(user => userConnected.Friends.Any(friend => user.UserId != friend.UserId))
```

After many try, I don't find how do this. I wondered if I really understand how this works.

Comment: what's the problem? you get an error or just don't get the data you want?

Comment: I don't have the good way to do this. Because I don't have result matches with my DB. I'll check @Peter 's answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For EF, **Contains** works well for this sort of problem. It is all about what EF is capable of turning into SQL. Try:

```
var friendIds = userConnected.Friends.Select(f=>f.UserId).ToList();
List<User> users = db.User
  .Where(user => user.Name.Contains(research)
  .Where(user => user.UserId != UserConnected.UserId)
  .Where(user => !friendIds.Contains(user.UserId))
.ToList();
```

Comment: It's work ! Thank you ! Do you want a beer as gift for this help ? :p 
Seriously, can you explain this a little more, please ? Because, when I read :  `.Where(user => !friendIds.Contains(user.UserId))` At first reading, I have the impression that it's the reverse condition.

Comment: From my understanding of your question you needed to add a condition that ensures the users returned are not already in the connected user's friend list. So you use not contains versus contains. It might help to understand how the EF expression gets translated to SQL. Contains gets turned into an IN predicate like this `user in (1,65,74)` so in your case you want `user not in (1,65,74)`